# Normal Stress Components of Viscous Stress Tensor for Incompressible Fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, navier-stokes

I am trying to get an intuitive understanding of the normal components of the stress tensor for a Newtonian Fluid.
The stress on the x face in the x direction is
$$\sigma_{xx} = 2*\mu\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $$
Where u is the velocity in the x direction.

I am trying to figure why this is the case.
In solid mechanics, the shear stress for an element under pure tension is maximum at 45$^o$ (this is evident from Mohr's circle. The resulting shear stress is $\frac{1}{2}\sigma$ with $\sigma$ being the normal stress applied.

So, coming back to the fluid "realm",I would then think (With Newton's Viscosity Law in mind) that the normal stress would be related to the shear stress by:
$$\sigma_{xx} = \frac{1}{2}*\mu\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $$
Where $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is the shear rate along the 45$^o$ plane.

It would help if someone could explain where my logic is off in terms of basic Newtonian mechanics and not tensor math.

Comment: Please consider proofreading your question, giving a little context, and clarifying what your drawings are intended to show. This will help people give you more focused answers.

Comment: From the continuity equation, $\epsilon_{xx}+\epsilon_{yy}+\epsilon_{zz}=0$.  From the non-slip boundary condition, $\epsilon_{yy}=\epsilon_{zz}=0$

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that the shear stress $\sigma_{xy}$ is half the normal stress $\sigma_{xx}$. In addition, however, the shear strain rate $\dot\varepsilon_{xy}$ is also half the normal strain rate $\dot\varepsilon_{xx}=\frac{du}{dx}$. (Explanation below*.)

The factor $\frac{1}{2}$ thus appears on both sides of the equation and cancels out.

The factor of two arises because $\frac{du}{dx}$ represents the tensorial strain rate. In pure shear, this strain rate is half the engineering shear strain $\dot\gamma$ used in Newton's law of viscosity $\tau=\mu\dot\gamma$, where $\tau$ is the shear stress. (Explanation below**.) **Thus, we must multiply it by two.**

***Explanation of stress and strain rate transformations:**

Consider pulling something axially at a constant rate:

[image]

(Images from [my site](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/overrating_youngs_modulus.htm).)

We can transform this normal stress and the normal strain rate into a combined shear and normal components by rotating the conceptual element by 45°:

[image]

The rotation transformation law for a 3×3 stress or strain rate tensor is $$\boldsymbol{\sigma^\prime}=\boldsymbol{a\sigma a^T},$$ where $\boldsymbol{a}$ is the [direction cosine matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Conversion_between_multiple_Cartesian_bases), or a matrix $a_{i,i^\prime}$ of cosines between the original axis and the rotated axis. Referring to your original question before editing, you're correct that $\sin(45^\circ)=\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$; the corresponding factor from *both* premultiplication and postmultiplication of $\boldsymbol a$ is one half.

If you don't care to get into the tensor operations, you can confirm graphically from [Mohr's circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%27s_circle) that a plotted circle for stress with sides at 0 and $\sigma_{11}$ has height $\frac{\sigma_{11}}{2}$, equivalent to the transformed shear stress $\sigma^\prime_{12}$. Put another way, the shear stress is half the normal stress.

Similarly, a plotted Mohr's circle for strain rate with sides at 0 and $\dot\varepsilon_{11}$ has height $\frac{\dot\varepsilon_{11}}{2}$, equivalent to the transformed shear strain rate $\dot\varepsilon_{12}^\prime$. This tensorial shear strain rate is half the engineering shear strain rate used in Newton's law of viscosity.

****Explanation of the relation between tensorial and engineering shear strain:**

The tensorial strain rate $\boldsymbol{\dot\varepsilon}$ or $\dot\varepsilon_{ij}$ is defined as

$$\dot\varepsilon_{ij}\equiv\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{du_i}{dx_j}+\frac{du_j}{dx_i}\right),$$

with velocity $u$ and direction $x$. This definition is handy because it applies to both normal and shear strain, but note that the tensorial shear strain rate ends up being half the engineering shear strain rate $\dot\gamma$, which is defined as the rate of change in a corner angle (in radians).

In general, therefore, for a Newtonian fluid, the stress $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ and strain rate $\boldsymbol{\dot\varepsilon}$ are coupled by the viscosity tensor $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ as

$$\boldsymbol{\sigma}=2\boldsymbol{\mu\dot\varepsilon};$$

$$\sigma_{ij}=2\mu_{ijkl}\dot\varepsilon_{kl},$$

which is just $\sigma=2\mu\frac{du}{dx}$ when linking the normal stress and strain rate, which is the equation you asked about.

Comment: So if we transform to the 45$o$ plane, the result would be $$\frac{1}{2}*\sigma = \sigma' = \mu*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ It makes sense to me how the $\frac{1}{2}$ cancels in this instance. But what exactly brings in the factor of 2? Do we have to transform back only the right hand side of the above equation, but not the left? How exactly is this equation I just wrote transformed into $\sigma = \mu*2*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$?

Comment: The equation you wrote is wrong; $\sigma\neq\mu\frac{du}{dx}$. I'm sorry, if you don't want to read the part about the difference between the tensorial shear strain rate $\dot\varepsilon_{12}\equiv\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\right)$ and the engineering shear strain rate $\dot\gamma\equiv\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}=2\dot\varepsilon_{12}$, then I can't help you. That, in conjunction with Newton's law of viscosity $\tau=\mu\dot\gamma$, is where the factor of two comes from.

Comment: I know my formula is wrong. You gave me the formula $\dot \gamma = 2*\dot \epsilon_{12}$, but I am not sure why this is the case. I tried sketching this and it does not make sense to me. Maybe I am thinking too hard about this.

Comment: See the animations under "Understanding normal and shear strains in 3D" [here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke's%20Law.htm), a work in progress.

Comment: I see in your note how the tensorial strains are defined, it was very helpful. My only question at this point is why the normal components of the tensorial strain get multiplied by 2*$\mu$ to create the stress tensor. I understand how the engineering **shear** stress components are defined, because both orthogonal gradients results in a total corner angle strain rate ,which is directly proportional to the viscous shear stress. But why are the normal tensorial strain elements multiplied by 2*$\mu$ to get the stress tensor? It is not obvious to me how the diagonal elements are formulated.

Comment: The shear strains of both edges of the conceptual rectangular element are added to give the change in the corner angle.

Comment: But there is no change in the corner angle with pure normal stress..

Comment: That's demonstrably falsified by the images I showed above. Nature doesn't care how you draw your conceptual element; the diagonal element shows a change in corner angle.