# Stress Tensor Normal Component (Newtonian Fluid)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain, navier-stokes

I am trying to get an intuitive understanding of the normal components of the stress tensor for a Newtonian Fluid.
The stress on the x face in the x direction is
$$\sigma_{xx} = 2*\mu\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $$
Where u is the velocity in the x direction.

I am trying to figure why this is the case.
In solid mechanics, the shear stress for an element under pure tension is maximum at 45$^o$ (this is evident from Mohr's circle. The resulting shear stress is $\frac{1}{2}\sigma$ with $\sigma$ being the normal stress applied.

So, coming back to the fluid "realm",I would then think (With Newton's Viscosity Law in mind) that the normal stress would be related to the shear stress by:
$$\sigma_{xx} = \frac{1}{2}*\mu\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $$
Where $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is the shear rate along the 45$^o$ plane.

It would help if someone could explain where my logic is off in terms of basic Newtonian mechanics and not tensor math.

Comment: Apparent duplicate of [Normal Stress Components of Viscous Stress Tensor for Incompressible Fluid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773466/normal-stress-components-of-viscous-stress-tensor-for-incompressible-fluid)

Comment: I wanted to explain my question better. I can't delete it.

Comment: You can edit it and vote to reopen. I gave several suggestions for improvement.

Comment: I did go back and re-edit the initial post.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I was unable to interpret your response to that question. I am still confused why we multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ twice and then by 2.

Comment: The standard approach, which works pretty well, is to add a comment under the answer asking for clarification. Please see my edited answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773504/146039).